# Is "j'" a contracted form of "je"?

Tags: grammaire, élision

I am a beginner. I learnt that "*Je suis un homme*" translates to "I am a man", but to say "I write", I should use "*J'écris*". Is "*j'*" a contracted form of "*je*" like "don't" for "do not"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*J'* is a *Je* indeed, but it is not the same as the *do not/don't* contraction.

In the case of *do not/don't*, you contract because you want to save some effort/time by biting one syllable.

In the case of *je/j'*, you don't get to choose whether you contract or not. It is a matter of pronunciation: when *je* is followed with a word beginning with a vowel, instead of pronouncing the *e* then the vowel, you eliminate the hiatus by removing the *e*.

In formal language, this is the only case when the *e* should disappear. In spoken French (or transcriptions, for books for instance), it is sometimes ignored nonetheless, and phrases like *je suis* are often pronounced *chuis* and transcripted as *j'suis*.

Comment: Is it a matter of pronunciation if formal French does not follow spoken French? And then, there is the problem of semi-vowels which can go both ways with different verbs *je ouate* [ʒəwat] vs *j'ois* [ʒwa] or with the same verb *je huile* vs *j'huile*...

Comment: Cases like _j'suis_ are informal: the elision is not here to avoid two vowels causing a hiatus. The rules for elision are clearly described. The case for _ouater/ouïr_ is interesting, but I suppose this comes from the infinitive form or an evolution of pronunciation. Some sounds avoid elision (as in English: you say _a uniform_, not _an uniform_). There are precise rules (which I cannot find), and there are the cases outside those rules, which are common in spoken French (like _j'suis_) or just plain mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "*J'écris*" is the contraction of *je* and *écris*. Unlike in English, contracted forms in the French language are mandatory.